# Summing columns with multiple constraints

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google sheet that has multiple projects worked by multiple individuals at various dates.

I have another column E which has individual names. 
In cell F1 I can pick a date and I am hoping to update total hours in cell F2, F3 and so on for respective individuals on that particular date. 
I was trying some lookup options but did not work. Maybe some `QUERY` can help ??

Here is the location of the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pyl-1vtjo-hOMzhWUST54szV6IL6gzk33pypRdP7DP4/edit#gid=0

[image: Snapshot of google sheets]

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: just made it accessible for all.

Answer (score 0):

paste in **F2** and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(C:C, A:A=E2, B:B=$F$1)), )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks a lot. I have to shortlist names who have no hours. I tried to use =QUERY(E2:E,"Select E where F is not null") but it is having some parsing error. (Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: F) can you suggest??

Comment: well, it kinda makes sense :) you selected range E2:E in query and in E2:E there is no F column - therefore that error

Comment: try: `=QUERY(E2:F,"Select E where F is not null")`

Comment: or: `=QUERY(E2:F,"Select * where F is not null")`

Comment: again thanks. however, after running this Query, for the first row, it shows three names in the same cell but rest follow with one name in one row.   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pyl-1vtjo-hOMzhWUST54szV6IL6gzk33pypRdP7DP4/edit#gid=0